# Django multiple select form - TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form like so:

```
class PartnerProductsForm(forms.Form):
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Product.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
            attrs={"checked": ""}
        ),
        empty_label=None,
    )
```

And my views:

```
...
product_form = PartnerProductsForm(request.POST or None)
    if product_form.is_valid():
        # do stuff
```

But when I submit I get the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

It seems like the form validation is expecting an int, but of course I will be retuning a list of the checked options. How am I supposed to deal with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The form field you're looking for is [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField), rather than `ModelChoiceField`.